# Captured DevTest Labs is not working

Tags: azure-devtest-labs

I have pressed the capture button on a VM in dev test labs. Now it looks like I have a generalized VM that looks useless to me. For example, I can not start the VM anymore. It just displays the following error message.

Failed to start virtual machine 'vmname'. Error: Operation 'start' is not allowed on VM 'vmname' since the VM is generalized.

I need to access this VM what can I do ?

** Should I have run sysprep before I hit the capture???

> As I can not start another VM it give this error. Provisioning failed.
>   OS Provisioning for VM 'IntegrationTest' did not finish in the
>   allotted time. However, the VM guest agent was detected running. This
>   suggests the guest OS has not been properly prepared to be used as a
>   VM image (with CreateOption=FromImage). To resolve this issue, either
>   use the VHD as is with CreateOption=Attach or prepare it properly for
>   use as an image:  * Instructions for Windows:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> > > > Don't use this button without SYSPREP.

Use regular backup.

IMHO the capture process is not as easy as AWS EC2... This error* caused us a day.

*It was my fault to hit the button where I thought it would just work. I should have tested it.

Comment: they do write this is traning books and it is not ALWAYS the issue.Until i lose a VM